# Permanently Disable/Ignore Secondary Disk?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a 256G SSD and a 1T HDD in my 27" iMac.

The 1T HDD is dying due to hardware failure.

Is there a file in OS X similar to `/etc/fstab` in Linux where I can prevent this 1T HDD from mounting?

I'd like to effectively disable/ignore this disk without needing to take it into an Apple store to be removed.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86257/how-can-i-tell-osx-not-to-mount-some-of-the-drives-in-my-computer/111024#111024

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

First get the UUID of the partition you want to prevent from mounting...  You can get this in Disk Utility "Get Info".

Now open your /etc/fstab file for editing:

```
sudo pico /etc/fstab
```

In this file add the following line (use your own UUID naturally):

```
UUID=[your UUID] none hfs rw,noauto 0 0
```

And save the file.

Restart for the change to take affect.

You can always mount it manually in Disk Utility.

Comment: Thank you. This works in terms of preventing the disk from mounting, but I can still hear what sounds like the needle scanning on the platters repeatedly. Can anything more be done to kill power to the drive altogether - short of opening up the iMac?

Comment: This does not work if the drive is not formatted.. there IS NO UUID!!!

Comment: Can Partition UUID be used here?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Linux.

The preferred disk identifier a Volume UUID.

You can use disk utility to find the Volume UUID or use diskutil:

> diskutil list

get the disk indentifier, e.g. disk0s4

> diskutil information disk0s4

In the row labeled Volume UUID:

> Volume UUID:              XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Edit /etc/fstab as root (it may not exist), creating an entry of the form:

UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX none hfs rw,noauto

Also refer to

> man -S5 fstab

Comment: Thank you. This works in terms of preventing the disk from mounting, but I can still hear what sounds like the needle scanning on the platters repeatedly. Can anything more be done to kill power to the drive altogether - short of opening up the iMac?

Comment: Have you unmounted it?  Are there more volumes on the same disk mounted?  Preferences > Energy Saver - Put hard disk to sleep when possible,  does it persist through a power down/boot up?

Comment: I went through a full power cycle, instead of restarting. The computer was off for about 8 hours. That seemed to fix it *(for now)*.

Comment: That puppy sounds seriously sick.

Comment: This does not work if the drive is not formatted.. there IS NO UUID!!!