# Disable "The disk you attached was not readable by this computer" for disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

When I enter a USB drive that is encrypted with veracrypt, I get an error message:

> The disk you attached was not readable by this computer
>
> Eject - Ignore - Initialize

Which I select "Ignore" because I will use the veracrypt tool to decrypt the drive. Is there a way to disable this dialog? I'm able to recognize the drive itself in Disk Utility. [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/permanently-disable-ignore-secondary-disk) prevents mounting the filesystem if its detected, but I'm at a stage before that: can I ignore the disk entirely without ejecting it?

Comment: I would assume if the flash drive contained a second small partition that would be mountable, then the message would not occur.