# Can I disable the "disable the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer"?

Tags: external-disk

I am writing a script to read files from external drives (thunderbolt to U.2 SSD), which have been formatted with the ext4 file system. Every time I connect one of those, I get a dialog with the message "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer", and every time I click on "Ignore". I can mount the drives with `ext4fuse`, so that isn't a problem, but this message is annoying me. Is there a way to tell the system to always automatically ignore this kind of drive?

I found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/443414/disable-the-disk-you-attached-was-not-readable-by-this-computer-for-disk), but there is no answer.