# Stop prompting to unlock disk

Tags: terminal, filesystem, filevault, automount

I have two hard disks on my 2012 Mac Mini. The first disk is partitioned with Mac HD and Data HD. The second drive has OS X Public Beta and Windows partitioned.

I want to prevent OS X on my main disk from auto-mounting OS X Public Beta and Windows 7. Both are encrypted (FileVault 2 and Bitlocker).

I tried to edit /etc/fstab and /private/etc/fstab which seem to be replicated but it doesn't work. I thought I was doing something wrong, so I added a line for Data HD which is not encrypted and it didn't mount.

sudo vifs

UUID=NUMBER none hfs ro,noauto

That's the line I'm issuing for Public Beta. I'm assuming its not hfs because of FV2 so is there another file system I need to enter? I also tried hfs+ and it didn't work, I still get prompted to enter passcode.

For Windows 7, I'm assuming I would use ntfs? I'm not using BootCamp so I don't think it would be fat.

Comment: Why don't you just keep the drive turned off until you need the Public Beta or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `UUID` try using `LABEL`. This will help to rule out UUID problems.

The following line in `/private/etc/fstab` stops the drive named **SpareSSHD** from mounting on OS X 10.10:

```
LABEL=SpareSSHD none    hfs rw,noauto
```

My drives are encrypted with FileVault2 and this works.

The following links provide more detail:

- [How can I tell OSX NOT to mount some of the drives in my computer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86257/how-can-i-tell-osx-not-to-mount-some-of-the-drives-in-my-computer)
- [fstab(5) manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/fstab.5.html)

`/private/etc/fstab` and `/etc/fstab` are the same file. As @forquare confirms, they are symlinked. You can edit either.

Comment: You are correct they are the same file, `/etc` is a symlink to `/private/etc` as you can see here: `lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11B Oct 20  2014 etc@ -> private/etc`

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.11.1 with a configuration like this, and it isn't working for me. I tried using the LABEL form, with the "Volume Name" from Disk Utility, and all the UUIDs associated with it. I still get a "Enter a password to unlock" prompt upon login, though this `fstab` change prevents the disk from actually mounting once I enter the password to unlock it. Is there another way to do this? Or something else that needs to be used for the LABEL?

Answer (score -1):

Try 'xx' instead of rw or ro. Since a FV2 drive doesn't mount until you unlock it, the rw,ro won't do anything.